# have record loaded when access gets focus

Tags: vba, ms-access-2007, dde

I have access 2007 as my DB engine for a PLC system. I use RSLinx as my DDE. Access is always loaded, Batch_Setup form as Popup and access minimized.

What I am trying to do is have the form Batch_Setup display the current batch information everytime access is maximized. I do a DDE request to get the current Formula_Number but I can not figure out how to make the form goto the Formula_Number.

Here is the VBA code:

```
Private Sub Form_Activate()
    Dim BATCH_NAME As String, STRX As String, LOOPX As Integer
    Dim TEMP_X As Integer
    abddeinitiate = DDEInitiate("RSLinx", "GCT")
    BATCH_NAME = DDERequest(abddeinitiate, "BATCH_NAME")

    STRX = 1
    LOOPX = 1
    While Not (STRX = "-")
        STRX = Mid(BATCH_NAME, LOOPX, 1)
        LOOPX = LOOPX + 1
    Wend

    LOOPX = LOOPX - 2
    STRX = Left(BATCH_NAME, LOOPX)
    TEMP_X = MsgBox(STRX, vbOKCancel)
    With Me.Recordset
        .FindFirst "FORMULA_NUMBER = " & CInt(STRX)
    End With

End Sub
```

I have tried Activate, GotFocus, Load, .... but I can not get it to goto the current batch setup. I can Find it thru the Find but I want it to goto it when Access is restored with the Batch_Setup form always loaded as Popup.